# How to use ontouch and onclick functions on a canvas, within a Class using different methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, this, addeventlistener

I've got a main.js calling a CanvasConstructor Class, in this one I make my canvas and manage the mouse for signing onto the canvas with different methods. That works!

Now I wanted to add methods to use it on smartphones (using ontouch events).

I can get only one position, which is not the actual position of my finger.

The ontouchmove() doesn't change the position either.

I tried to get my canvas by getElementById(), the problem was the same.

I assume that I've got some problems with getting the different contexts within my Class, so it's one part of the global problem.

The second problem is how to manage the ontouch events correctly.

(Sorry for my English and my JS skills, I try my best).

index.html:

```html
<canvas class="canvas-style" id="canvas" width="200" height="70"></canvas>
```

main.js:

```js
const canvas = new CanvasConstructor();

canvas.mouseConstructor();
canvas.touchConstructor();

/* I usually comment one of them to test each other */
```

canvas.js:

```js
class CanvasConstructor{
    constructor(){
        this.color = "#000";
        this.painting = false;
        this.started = false;
        this.width_brush = 2;
        this.canvas = $("#canvas");
        this.cursorX; this.cursorY;
        this.restoreCanvasArray = [];
        this.restoreCanvasIndex = 0;

        this.context = this.canvas[0].getContext('2d');

    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
}

    mouseConstructor(){
        var self = this;
        this.canvas.mousedown(function(e) {

            this.painting = true;

        this.cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft); 
        this.cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);  
    });

    this.canvas.mouseup(function() {
        this.painting = false;
        this.started = false;
    });
    
    this.canvas.mousemove(function(e) {

        if (this.painting) {

            this.cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - 10;
            this.cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - 10; 

            self.drawLine(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
        }
    });
    self.reset();
}

touchConstructor(){
    var self = this;

    this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        this.painting = true;
        console.log("touchSTART!!");
        this.cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft); 
        this.cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);



    }, false);

    this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        this.painting = false;
        this.started = false;   

    }, false);

    this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        if (this.painting) {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            this.cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft); 
            this.cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);

            self.drawLine(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
        }
    }, false);

    self.reset();
}


    drawLine(cursorX, cursorY) {
    
        if (!this.started) {
        
            this.context.beginPath();
            this.context.moveTo(cursorX, cursorY);
            this.started = true;
        } 
    
        else {
            this.context.lineTo(cursorX, cursorY);
            this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
            this.context.lineWidth = this.width_brush;
            this.context.stroke();
        }
    }
    

    clear_canvas() {
        this.context.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width(), this.canvas.height());
    }
    
    

    reset(){
        var self = this;
        $("#reset").click(function() {

        self.clear_canvas();
        
    });
    }
}
```

When you touch the canvas you get the ontouchstart(), onctouchend() and ontouchmove() functions, but it doesn't draw because I can't get the actual position of the touching.

Please explain me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update the touchConstructor function as follow.

```
touchConstructor(){

 var self = this;

 this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.painting = true;
    console.log("touchSTART!!");



    var pageX = e.touches[0].pageX; //to get pageX value in touch devices
    var pageY = e.touches[0].pageY; //to get pageY value in touch devices  



    this.cursorX = (pageX - this.offsetLeft); 
    this.cursorY = (pageY - this.offsetTop);



}, false);

this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    this.painting = false;
    this.started = false;   

}, false);

this.canvas[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    if (this.painting) {
        e.preventDefault(); 



        var pageX = e.touches[0].pageX; //to get pageX value in touch devices
        var pageY = e.touches[0].pageY; //to get pageY value in touch devices  



        this.cursorX = (pageX - this.offsetLeft); 
        this.cursorY = (pageY - this.offsetTop);

        self.drawLine(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
    }
}, false);

self.reset();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get : e.originalEvent is undefined.

Comment: Sorry it was for jQuery and now I have updated it for pure javascript.

Comment: I'm now getting : TypeError: setting getter-only property "pageX".

Comment: ok it is giving error while assigning updated value to e.pageX, 
I have updated the code

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, I will upvote your answer when I'll be able to do so.

Comment: Can you explain why on the touch methods we have to use this.canvas[0] instead of this.canvas (which is working for the mouse but not on onTouch methods)?

Comment: here you are using e.touches[0].pageX instead of e.pageX.